# Request body empty with Node PUT from Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, put

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for a few hours. I'm not sure why it doesn't work but it's probably something simple I'm missing. It usually is...

Anyway, I'm doing a simple HTTP PUT from Angular 7 like this:

```
protected put(cmd: string, body: any) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();                           
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

    console.log(body);

    return this._http.put(cmd, body, {headers: headers});
  }
```

cmd and body are being passed in. I can see the body print out in the console and the cmd path is correct to hit my route path in Node.

From there, it comes into my Node/Express app. Which goes as follows:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use('/api', require('./routes/routes'));
app.use('/api/add-user', require('./routes/add-user/routes'));

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

And this is my routes file that console prints the empty body:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dvAdmin = require('../../controller/controller');

//Routes

//GETS

//PUTS
router.put('/addCCUser', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: any chance you are really submitting a json string (that maybe is not a valid json)?

Comment: just a note, **not** related to issue, but you are actually not setting your headers, `HttpHeaders` (and `HttpParams`) are immutable and always return a new instance. Might be useful for future :)

Comment: Thanks, @NormundsKalnberzins, that was it. I was using an earlier version of an api and they were stringifying the body before sending it, so I did the same. Turns out I don't need to do that with my current version.